# How can we pass java object to groovyx.net.http.RestClient's POST call

Tags: java, spock, rest-client

I have written a `Restfull` webservice `POST` api call, this api is accepting `java object` as request parameter

Sample code:

```
@POST
@Path("/sample")
@ApiOperation(value = "insert sample data",
        notes = "insert sample data", response = SampleRequest.class)
public Response processSampleData(@ApiParam(value = "SampleRequest", required = true) SampleRequest sampleRequest) {
   //code to insert data
}
```

I am writing an Integration test method, but not able to pass `java object` to the `RestClient`

Sample test method:

```
def "process sample data"(){
    when:
    /*String json = '{"sampleDataList":[{ "name": "test1", "id": "12345" },{ "name": "test2", "id": "123456"}]}'*/
    Sample sample= new Sample();
    sample.setName("test1");
    sample.setId("12345");
    SampleRequest reqObj = new SampleRequest();
    reqObj.getSampleList().add(sample);

    //tried with json
    /*HttpResponseDecorator response = getRestClient().post([path: "$BASE_URL"+"/sample", body: json])*/

    //tried with java object also
    HttpResponseDecorator response = getRestClient().post([path: "$BASE_URL"+"/sample", body: SampleRequest])

    then:
    response
}
```

I tried using both `json` and `java object` but none of them worked for me. Getting `No encoder found for request content type */*` error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I added `contentType: "application/json` then it worked for `json` body type.

I changed

```
HttpResponseDecorator response = getRestClient().post([path: "$BASE_URL"+"/sample",body: json])
```

To

```
HttpResponseDecorator response = getRestClient().post([path: "$BASE_URL"+"/sample",contentType: "application/json" ,body: json])
```